# Midi.js how to play?

Tags: javascript, android, html, midi

i want to hear a sound with an example of mudcube Midi.js demo-basic.html but i can't hear a sound. could anyone help me? i'm just a beginner thank you

```
    <html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <!-- midi.js package -->
     <script src="./js/MIDI/AudioDetect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="./js/MIDI/LoadPlugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="./js/MIDI/Plugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="./js/MIDI/Player.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="./js/Window/DOMLoader.XMLHttp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <!-- extras -->
     <script src="./inc/Base64.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="./inc/base64binary.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            window.onload = function () {
                MIDI.loadPlugin({
                    soundfontUrl: "./soundfont/",
                    instrument: "acoustic_grand_piano",
                    callback: function() {
                var delay = 0; // play one note every quarter second
                var note = 50; // the MIDI note
                var velocity = 127; // how hard the note hits
                // play the note
        MIDI.setVolume(0, 127);
        MIDI.noteOn(0, note, velocity, delay);
        MIDI.noteOff(0, note, delay + 0.75);
    }
        });
    };

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You are not getting answers because the question does not contain enough code for anyone to run. We would need to download all the other JavaScript libraries referenced in the page in order to create a demo. You might want to look at creating a demo of the problem, for example on [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net), where you can link to online versions of the .js files.

Answer (score 1):

There is a a Cross Origin Request happening which is not letting the Soundfont get uploaded. You would be able to see that in the Google Chrome console. It is currently an open issue on the midi.js Github repo. (https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/issues/63). There are a few suggestions there which will help you get it up and running till they push a version where this is addressed.

Answer (score 0):

It works in FireFox browser.  I couldn't get it to play one note at a time though.  I had it in a loop to paly 3 different notes one at a time but they all played like a chord.

Answer (score 0):

try this code.  The timing isn't correct as it is work in progress lol but it is supposed to play happy birthday.

```
onsuccess: function() { var delay = 0; // play one note every quarter second
var note = 50; // the MIDI note
var velocity = 127; // how hard the note hits
var i;  
var Note1Play = [60, 60, 62, 60, 65, 64, 60, 60];
var Length1_Note = [0.455, 0.455, 0.91, 0.91, 0.91, 1.82, 0.455, 0.455];
MIDI.setVolume(0, 127);
delay = .455;
for (i=0; i<=24; i++){
  delay = delay + Length1_Note[i];
  MIDI.noteOn(0, Note1Play[i], velocity,delay);
  MIDI.noteOff(0,Note1Play[i],delay + 32);
}    }    });    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the correct script sources, this code plays the "Happy Birthday" song:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            MIDI.loadPlugin({
                onsuccess: function () {
                    var delay = 0; // play one note every quarter second
                    var note = 50; // the MIDI note
                    var velocity = 127; // how hard the note hits
                    var i;
                    var Note1Play =    [60,   60,  67,  67,  69,  69, 67,  65,  65,  64,  64,  62,  62, 60 ];
                    var Length1_Note = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,  1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5];
                    MIDI.setVolume(0, 127);
                    delay = 0;
                    for (i = 0; i <= Length1_Note.length; i++) {
                        delay = delay + Length1_Note[i];
                        MIDI.noteOn(0, Note1Play[i], velocity, delay);
                        MIDI.noteOff(0, Note1Play[i], delay + 25);
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    </script>
```

(there is a button that have an onclick fuction named myFunction)
Im running this on Microsoft Edge. I cannot be able to hear the sound on Chrome due to CORS policy.